# How to use a parameter in databricks dbfs cp command

Tags: scala, databricks

I want to copy a file from one mount location to other using `dbfs cp`  command in Databricks Scala notebook, and I want to use source and destination as parameters. How can I do it?

My code is giving error:

```
val source = "/mnt/source/data.txt"
val dest = "/mnt/destination/"

%fs ls (source)

dbfs cp (source,dest)
```

Error:

```
command-2950136022187373:2: error: not found: value %
%fs ls (source)
^

error: not found: value dbfs
dbfs cp dbfs:/mnt/source/data.txt dbfs:/mnt/destination/
^
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, `dbfs` works only Databricks cli. You need to use the `dbutils` command if you are using Databricks notebook. Try this:

```
dbutils.fs.cp(var_sourcepath,var_destinationpath,True)
```

Set the third parameter to `True` if you want to copy files **recursively**.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit,But it doesn't work.

Code:

val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/mnt/config/CopyFile.json")
val source = df.select("Source")
val dest = df.select("Destination")

dbutils.fs.cp(source,dest,True)



Error:
command-2950136022187370:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: String
dbutils.fs.cp(source,dest,True)

Comment: Source and destination in your code seems to be dataframes. You'll have to save the dataframes as a csv and give the saved paths as parameters in the dbutils part for the code to work.

Comment: i could do it using below code:

val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/mnt/app.json")
val sourcepath = df.select("source").collect()(0)(0).toString
val targetpath = df.select("destination").collect()(0)(0).toString

dbutils.fs.mv(sourcepath,targetpath ,true)

Comment: Yep, you have converted the dataframe to a string. So the file you are reading contains the file paths is it? Also mv moves the file, you wanted to copy the file if I'm not wrong. Would suggest you to use cp in that case.